# Is it possible to draw a report without using birt report designer？

Tags: birt

I have a big issue with birt report recently. We all know that we can use birt report designer to draw a report by drag some report elements from palette. But,my leader have a point that if we can draw a simple report without using birt report designer?

Comment: A BIRT report is simply a XML file if I'm not mistaken. And you can create XML files with any text editor.

Comment: In fact,I misunderstood my leader's meaning.He asks me to use a Excel file which can be a template,and create the report according to the data dynamically..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel as a data source and then use the API to pull information out of that or build a report. As mentioned earlier, you can also create the XML that defines the report outside of the designer as well. You could also write JavaScript or other client side code to take the Excel file and extract data from that to use in a report.